# Firebase email verfication not redirecting to expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase

I am trying to implement passwordless email link authentication with firebase and Im using react native with expo,I already received email verification link,but issue it is not redirecting to my app,Im using expo deep link and already set https://my.page.link/j5nk as allowed domain in the firebase, below is my code

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
handleCodeInApp: true,
// URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
url: "https://my.page.link/j5nk",

android: {
packageName: BUNDLE_ID,
installApp: true,
minimumVersion: "12",
},
};

const handleVerification = async () => {
try {
await auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(mail, actionCodeSettings);
setIsEmailSent(true);
setMail(mail);

Alert.alert(`Verification link sent to ${mail}`);
console.log("Verification link sent to the email:", mail);
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error sending verification link:", error);
setIsEmailSent(false); // Set isEmailSent to false if there's an error
Alert.alert("Error sending verification link:", error.message);
}
};
```

below is handle link function

```
 const verifyEmailLink = async (url) => {
    try {
      const isEmailVerified = await auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(url);
      return isEmailVerified;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error verifying email link:", error);
      return false;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInitialUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
        if (initialUrl) {
          const isEmailVerified = await verifyEmailLink(initialUrl);

          if (isEmailVerified) {
            // Email is verified, navigate to the signup screen
            router.push({ pathname: pages.auth.register });
          } else {
            console.warn("Invalid email verification link.");
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting initial URL:", error);
        Alert.alert("Error", "An error occurred while handling the deep link.");
      }
    };

    getInitialUrl();
  }, [router]);
```